# Yoast SEO (WordPress Plugin) - Get plugin generated data manually

Tags: php, wordpress, yoast

I wanted to get the Yoast SEO generated data manually, see example code below

This data is being generated by Yoast and automatically add it inside the **head tag**.

```
<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast SEO plugin v4.2.1 - https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/ -->
<meta name="description" content="bla bla bla"/>
<meta name="robots" content="noodp"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.localhost.com/" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="bla bla bla" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.localhost.com/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Example.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/example.png" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="bla bla bla." />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="bla bla bla" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://example.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/example.png" />
<script type='application/ld+json'>{"@context":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"WebSite","@id":"#website","url":"http:\/\/example.localhost.com\/","name":"Example","potentialAction":{"@type":"SearchAction","target":"http:\/\/example.localhost.com\/?s={search_term_string}","query-input":"required name=search_term_string"}}</script>
<!-- / Yoast SEO plugin. -->
```

I do not want to use **wp_head();** because it also generates other scripts, styles and whatever plugin or code you have in your wordpress website.

I do not need all those codes. I only want to get the Yoast SEO generated code as shown above. any ideas how could i do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the yoast meta in any page by `get_post_meta()`,

get the meta values by following,

```
echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true); 
echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_title', true);
```

Check the `post_meta` table to get all the values related to each page/post.

Answer (score 3):

Use this below:

```
do_action( 'wpseo_head' );
```

It will print all SEO header in your head. No need to add through post meta.

Answer (score 0):

It's four years later, so things have changed here.
The data can now be retrieved via API in a structured way:
Example:

```
echo YoastSEO()->meta->for_current_page()->description;
```

See:
https://developer.yoast.com/customization/apis/surfaces-api/

Also via REST a access is possible:
https://developer.yoast.com/customization/apis/rest-api

May that sometimes helps.
To get the meta at all (unstruktured), the both other ways are sufficient.